# I am trying to write regex expression in java script for string '$val' or '$val1' where digit can be optional but $val should match

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write regex expression in java script for string '$val' or '$val1' where digit can be optional but $val should match

Current regex expression is 
var rexp = /\$val\d+/gi;

This works only for $val1 or $val2 but not for $val.

Comment: Use `/\$val\d*/gi`

Comment: Read a tutorial first instead of asking on stackoverflow.

Comment: I tried this but not working. Actually I am trying to get $val from  string using  "$val > 2".match(rexp);

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/xc76t99o/, it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your `regex` just need a little bit modification.

```
var regex = /(\$val)|(\$val\d+)/g;
var value = "$val";

value.match(regex);
```

Ok so lets get this straight. We're checking for two conditions using a pipe | (OR) operator, one without any digit `(\$val)` and the second with digit `(\$val\d+)` and rest of the regex is all same.

#### UPDATE:

And according to @csander suggested regex with some modifications, you can use it in order to return regex match along with digits.

```
var regex = /\$val(\d?)+/;
```

Comment: I tried with var regex = /\$val\d?+/; but it is giving me error "Nothing to repeat"

Comment: Your answer is right and it's working in jsFiddle but some how it's not working in my javascript. Really don't know why. I am using JQuery javascript function.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with your code which is not working, and mention the link here.

Comment: Finally I have used    var rexp = /(\\$val)|(\\$val\d+)/gi; and now it's working. Thanks for your help HAmza

Comment: Finally if you got the solution working, you may mark this as correct answer, just so others may find this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `+`. That means one or more digits. Instead, you want `/\$val\d?/g`.

Comment: Works fine for me. `"$val > 2".match(/\$val\d?/)` returns a successful match.

Comment: Tried again. Below is my code.                                                                   
  var rexp = /\$val\d?/;     
 var matches_array = condExp.match(rexp);                           
   matches_array is comming null